# convert nodejs server in minicap example to python version

Tags: python, node.js

Recently , I want to plan convert an example in "minicap" project ,here is the link:Click [here](https://github.com/openstf/minicap/blob/master/example/app.js)

In this example,the author write the server in nodejs and client in script, server like below:

```
    var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
      , http = require('http')
      , express = require('express')
      , path = require('path')
      , net = require('net')
      , app = express()

    var PORT = process.env.PORT || 9002

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')))

    var server = http.createServer(app)
    var wss = new WebSocketServer({ server: server })

    wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
      console.info('Got a client')

      var stream = net.connect({
        port: 1717
      })

      stream.on('error', function() {
        console.error('Be sure to run `adb forward tcp:1717 localabstract:minicap`')
        process.exit(1)
      })

      var readBannerBytes = 0
      var bannerLength = 2
      var readFrameBytes = 0
      var frameBodyLength = 0
      var frameBody = new Buffer(0)
      var banner = {
        version: 0
      , length: 0
      , pid: 0
      , realWidth: 0
      , realHeight: 0
      , virtualWidth: 0
      , virtualHeight: 0
      , orientation: 0
      , quirks: 0
      }

      function tryRead() {
        for (var chunk; (chunk = stream.read());) {
          console.info('chunk(length=%d)', chunk.length)
          for (var cursor = 0, len = chunk.length; cursor < len;) {
            if (readBannerBytes < bannerLength) {
              switch (readBannerBytes) {
              case 0:
                // version
                banner.version = chunk[cursor]
                break
              case 1:
                // length
                banner.length = bannerLength = chunk[cursor]
                break
              case 2:
              case 3:
              case 4:
              case 5:
                // pid
                banner.pid +=
                  (chunk[cursor] << ((readBannerBytes - 2) * 8)) >>> 0
                break
              case 6:
              case 7:
              case 8:
              case 9:
                // real width
                banner.realWidth +=
                  (chunk[cursor] << ((readBannerBytes - 6) * 8)) >>> 0
                break
              case 10:
              case 11:
              case 12:
              case 13:
                // real height
                banner.realHeight +=
                  (chunk[cursor] << ((readBannerBytes - 10) * 8)) >>> 0
                break
              case 14:
              case 15:
              case 16:
              case 17:
                // virtual width
                banner.virtualWidth +=
                  (chunk[cursor] << ((readBannerBytes - 14) * 8)) >>> 0
                break
              case 18:
              case 19:
              case 20:
              case 21:
                // virtual height
                banner.virtualHeight +=
                  (chunk[cursor] << ((readBannerBytes - 18) * 8)) >>> 0
                break
              case 22:
                // orientation
                banner.orientation += chunk[cursor] * 90
                break
              case 23:
                // quirks
                banner.quirks = chunk[cursor]
                break
              }

              cursor += 1
              readBannerBytes += 1

              if (readBannerBytes === bannerLength) {
                console.log('banner', banner)
              }
            }
            else if (readFrameBytes < 4) {
              frameBodyLength += (chunk[cursor] << (readFrameBytes * 8)) >>> 0
              cursor += 1
              readFrameBytes += 1
              console.info('headerbyte%d(val=%d)', readFrameBytes, frameBodyLength)
            }
            else {
              if (len - cursor >= frameBodyLength) {
                console.info('bodyfin(len=%d,cursor=%d)', frameBodyLength, cursor)

                frameBody = Buffer.concat([
                  frameBody
                , chunk.slice(cursor, cursor + frameBodyLength)
                ])

                // Sanity check for JPG header, only here for debugging purposes.
                if (frameBody[0] !== 0xFF || frameBody[1] !== 0xD8) {
                  console.error(
                    'Frame body does not start with JPG header', frameBody)
                  process.exit(1)
                }

                ws.send(frameBody, {
                  binary: true
                })

                cursor += frameBodyLength
                frameBodyLength = readFrameBytes = 0
                frameBody = new Buffer(0)
              }
              else {
                console.info('body(len=%d)', len - cursor)

                frameBody = Buffer.concat([
                  frameBody
                , chunk.slice(cursor, len)
                ])

                frameBodyLength -= len - cursor
                readFrameBytes += len - cursor
                cursor = len
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }

      stream.on('readable', tryRead)

      ws.on('close', function() {
        console.info('Lost a client')
        stream.end()
      })
    })

    server.listen(PORT)
    console.info('Listening on port %d', PORT)
```

I write this code below in python using tornado, this is my first time to learn node.js, and in my computer, I download NDK filed, because the first time to write, there exists many errors, wish somebody to support me.This is my code :

```
    #coding:UTF-8        
    import tornado.web
    import tornado.websocket
    import tornado.httpserver
    import tornado.ioloop
    import struct

    class IndexPageHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
            self.render('index.html')

    class WebSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
        def open(self):
            print 'Got a client'

        def on_message(self,message):
            readBannerBytes = 0
            bannerLength = 2
            readFrameBytes = 0
            frameBodyLength = 0
            frameBody = []

            banner ={"version": 0,
                     "length": 0,
                     "pid": 0,
                     "realWidth": 0,
                     "realHeight": 0,
                     "virtualWidth": 0,
                     "virtualHeight": 0,
                     "orientation": 0,
                     "quirks": 0
                     }
            for cursor in len(message):
                if readBannerBytes < bannerLength:
                    readBannerBytes = list(i for i in range(24))
                    if readBannerBytes == 0:
                        banner["version"] = message[cursor]
                    elif readBannerBytes == 1:
                        banner["length"] = bannerLength = message[cursor]
                    elif readBannerBytes == 5:
                        banner["pid"] += (message[cursor] << ((readBannerBytes - 2) * 8))
                    elif readBannerBytes == 9:
                        banner["realWidth"] += (message[cursor] << ((readBannerBytes - 6) * 8))
                    elif readBannerBytes == 13:
                        banner["realHeight"] += (message[cursor] << ((readBannerBytes - 10) * 8))
                    elif readBannerBytes == 17:
                        banner["virtualWidth"] += (message[cursor] << ((readBannerBytes - 14) * 8))
                    elif readBannerBytes == 21:
                        banner["virtualHeight"] += (message[cursor] << ((readBannerBytes - 18) * 8))
                    elif readBannerBytes == 22:
                        banner["orientation"] += message[cursor] * 90
                    elif readBannerBytes == 23:
                        banner["quirks"] = message[cursor]
                    cursor += 1
                    readBannerBytes += 1
                    if readBannerBytes == bannerLength:
                        print   'banner:',banner

                elif readFrameBytes < 4:
                    frameBodyLength += (message[cursor] << (readFrameBytes * 8))
                    cursor += 1
                    readFrameBytes += 1
                    print   'headerbyte%d(val=%d)', readFrameBytes, frameBodyLength
                else:
                    if len - cursor >= frameBodyLength:
                        print   'bodyfin(len=%d,cursor=%d)', frameBodyLength, cursor
                        framBody = frameBody + message[cursor, cursor + frameBodyLength]
                        if (framBody[0] != 0xFF) or (framBody[1] != 0xD8):
                            print   'Frame body does not start with JPG header', frameBody
                            sys.exit(1)
                        cursor += framBodyLength
                        frameBodyLength = readFrameBytes = 0
                        framBody = []
                    else:
                        print   'body(len=%d)', (len - curs)
                        framBody = framBody + chunk[cursor, len]
                        frameBodyLength -= len - cursor
                        readFrameBytes += len - cursor
                        cursor = len

        def on_close(self):
            print   'Lost a client'

    class Application(tornado.web.Application):
        def __init__(self):
            handlers = [(r'/', IndexPageHandler),
                        (r'/ws', WebSocketHandler)
            ]
            settings = { "public": "."}
            tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers, **settings)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        ws_app = Application()
        server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(ws_app)
        server.listen(1717)
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

My question is :

***1.the python server should parse the message from client using module struct;***

***2.my code errors in my python version;***

Thanks a lot!

Comment: SO doesn't want any data like this in links. The question itself should be enough to be answered. In addition I would think this question might be too broad, like, what have you tried, what is not working? A lot easier to answer if the question is as specific as possible.

Comment: did you write the entire code without testing? Usually you test bits and pieces first. This is still a very vague question. You don't even mention what error you get.

Comment: you say right, in my computer, I download NDK failed, and not to test.